# Django import-export name 'name' is not defined

Tags: python, django, excel, import

Hello guys I need import excel file in django admin I found this this video and I applied the steps but I have Line number: `1 - name 'name' is not defined error` how can I solve this?

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Ekle(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, blank = False)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    price = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

    def __str__(self):
        return name
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin


@admin.register(Ekle)
class ViewAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use self along with it:

```
def __str__(self):
    return "%s" % self.name
```

Comment: thanks i donts see error now but data's looking blank